# Mongo query syntax error

Tags: regex, mongodb

I don't understand why one of these syntaxs work and the other one doesn't. It's my understanding that they both pretty much mean the same.

**This works**

```
{ 'profile.fname' : { $regex:  ".*" + this.queryParams.value + ".*", $options: '-i'}},
```

**This does not work**

```
{ profile : { fname : { $regex:  ".*" + this.queryParams.value + ".*", $options: '-i'}}},
```

Example data structure looks like:

```
{
"_id":"ybhng3YCu4W4MSzz9",
"createdAt":"2016-08-23T10:44:33.088Z",
"emails":[{"address":"xy@z.co.uk","verified":false}],
"profile":
{
"fname":"name",
"lname":"otherName"
},
"roles":["admin"]
}
```

The first one produces the correct result but the second one produces nothing - as in an empty array. From debugging I know this must be the wrong syntax somewhere but I cannot see it.

I am using meteor as the server side.

Comment: Structurally, it looks like fname in the second one is in a sub structure of profile, while in the first, it's a member of profile.

Comment: @sln Updated it with example dataset

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are querying against an embedded document, you need to use dot notation like you're doing in your first query.

If you supply it a document, it must be an exact match. In this case you'd literally need:

```
{ profile: { fname: "name", lname :"otherName"} }
```

Of course this looks like bad design to me; why is profile an embedded document in the first place? Instead of something like this:

```
{
"_id":"ybhng3YCu4W4MSzz9",
"createdAt":"2016-08-23T10:44:33.088Z",
"emails":[{"address":"xy@z.co.uk","verified":false}],

"fname":"name",
"lname":"otherName"

"roles":["admin"]
}
```

**Reference:** [Query on Embedded Documents](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/query-documents/#read-operations-embedded-documents)

Comment: Thanks. Profile is an extension of the core meteor accounts schema.